# WMI Win32_SoundDevice J-Interop throws Unknown name exception

Tags: java, wmi, com-interop, wmi-query

I am trying to get `Win32_SoundDevice` and `Win32_VideoController`Hardware id but getting Win32_SoundDevice instance throws **Unknow Name Exception**

here is my code

```
package com.az;

import static org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIProgId.valueOf;
import static org.jinterop.dcom.impls.JIObjectFactory.narrowObject;
import static org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.IJIDispatch.IID;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException;
import org.jinterop.dcom.common.JISystem;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.IJIComObject;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIArray;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JISession;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIString;
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIVariant;
import org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.IJIDispatch;
import org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.IJIEnumVariant;

public class PerformanceMonitor extends JApplet {

    String domain = "az.com.us";
    String hostname = "mc-us-az";
    String username = "az";
    String password = "test_az_";

    public JIComServer comServer = null;

    public JISession dcomSession = null;

    public IJIDispatch wbemServices = null;

    public Object[] params = null;


    public static final String soundCardInfo = "Win32_SoundDevice"; 

public void setWindowsCredentials(String domain, String hostname, String username, String password) {
        try {
            dcomSession = init(domain, username, password);
            comServer = new JIComServer(valueOf("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"), hostname, dcomSession);
            IJIDispatch wbemLocator = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(comServer.createInstance().queryInterface(IID));

            params = new Object[] { new JIString(hostname), new JIString("ROOT\\CIMV2"), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
                    JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), new Integer(0), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM() };
            JIVariant results[] = wbemLocator.callMethodA("ConnectServer", params);
            wbemServices = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(results[0].getObjectAsComObject());



            getWMISoundCard(getJIVariants(wbemLocator, soundCardInfo));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dcomSession != null) {
                try {
                    JISession.destroySession(dcomSession);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }   

private void getWMISoundCard(JIVariant[] diskMonit) {

        try {
            IJIDispatch wbemObjectSet = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(diskMonit[0].getObjectAsComObject());

            JIVariant newEnumvariant = wbemObjectSet.get("_NewEnum");
            IJIComObject object2 = newEnumvariant.getObjectAsComObject();
            IJIEnumVariant enumVARIANT = (IJIEnumVariant) narrowObject(object2.queryInterface(IJIEnumVariant.IID));

            JIVariant countVariant = wbemObjectSet.get("Count");
            int numberOfServices = countVariant.getObjectAsInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfServices; i++) {
                Object[] elements = enumVARIANT.next(1);
                JIArray aJIArray = (JIArray) elements[0];

                JIVariant[] array = (JIVariant[]) aJIArray.getArrayInstance();
                for (JIVariant variant : array) {
                    IJIDispatch wbemObjectDispatch = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(variant.getObjectAsComObject());

                    JIVariant[] v = wbemObjectDispatch.callMethodA("GetObjectText_", new Object[] { 1 });

                    JIVariant deviceID = (JIVariant) (wbemObjectDispatch.get("DeviceID"));

                    System.out.println("SoundCard Device ID =" + deviceID.getObjectAsString2());                    

                }
            }
        } catch (JIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public JIVariant[] getJIVariants(IJIDispatch wbemServices, String task) {
        JIVariant[] arrJIVariant = null;
        try {
            params = new Object[] { new JIString(task), new Integer(0), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM() };

            arrJIVariant = wbemServices.callMethodA("InstancesOf", params);
        } catch (JIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrJIVariant;
    }

private static JISession init(String domain, String user, String pass) throws Exception {
        JISystem.getLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
        JISystem.setAutoRegisteration(true);

        JISession dcomSession = JISession.createSession(domain, user, pass);
        dcomSession.useSessionSecurity(false);
        return dcomSession;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        PerformanceMonitor performanceMonitor = new PerformanceMonitor();
        performanceMonitor.setWindowsCredentials(performanceMonitor.domain, performanceMonitor.hostname, performanceMonitor.username, performanceMonitor.password);
    }

}
```

> Stack Trace

```
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Unknown name. [0x80020006]
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.call(JIComServer.java:910)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.call(JIComServer.java:856)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComObjectImpl.call(JIComObjectImpl.java:266)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComObjectImpl.call(JIComObjectImpl.java:153)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.JIDispatchImpl.getIDsOfNames(JIDispatchImpl.java:109)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.JIDispatchImpl.callMethodA(JIDispatchImpl.java:477)
    at com.az.PerformanceMonitor.getJIVariants(PerformanceMonitor.java:682)
    at com.az.PerformanceMonitor.setWindowsCredentials(PerformanceMonitor.java:123)
    at com.az.PerformanceMonitor.init(PerformanceMonitor.java:80)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIRuntimeException: Unknown name. [0x80020006]
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JICallBuilder.readResult(JICallBuilder.java:1079)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JICallBuilder.read(JICallBuilder.java:957)
    at ndr.NdrObject.decode(NdrObject.java:36)
    at rpc.ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.call(ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.java:137)
    at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:113)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.call(JIComServer.java:901)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
getWMISoundCard(getJIVariants(wbemLocator, soundCardInfo));
```

with this

```
getWMISoundCard(getJIVariants(wbemServices, soundCardInfo));
```

and problem solved